# Does Travelin' Farmer deal damage when owner replaces him?

Tags: card-wars

In "Adventure time Card Wars Finn vs Jake" there is a *Travelin' Farmer* creature with description:

> When Travelin' Farmer leaves play, deal 1 Damage to your opponent for each card in his hand.

Can player replace the creature to trigger this ability and deal damage to opponent?

[image: travelin' farmer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes, replacement counts as "leave a play"

This is clarified at boadgamegeek.com [forum](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1129446/random-assorted-questions). The author [asks](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1129446/article/15007102#15007102)

> Does "leaves play" only refer to when the Travelin' Farmer is defeated in battle, or can the owner of this creature replace him and do damage to his opponent at the same time?

And here is [the answer](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1129446/article/15007324#15007324) from the Matt Hyra (one of the game designers; you can see his name in credits section of the [rule book](https://cryptozoic.com/sites/default/files/icme/u2082/at_card_wars_rulebook3_0.pdf)):

> Creatures leave play when defeated in combat, when you replace them, or if you use an effect to return it to your hand. Each way makes him work.